# How to use gawk to print out the 3rd column that is greater than 10 characters regardless of comma in the string

Tags: awk, text-processing, text-parsing

I have a csv file where some of the addresses have a comma in the middle, because of this I can't use

```
$ awk -F',' 'length($3) >= 10 {print $3}' schools.csv
```

an example of my data looks like this

```
id,name,address
"1","paul","103 avenue"
"2","shawn","108 BLVD, SE"
"3","ryan","MLK drive 1004"
```

as you can see the address for id two has a comma in between so I have to use gawk module 4. So far I've been able to print every row regardless if there is a comma or not but I only want to print the 3rd column(address) that has a field > 10 characters. Here is what I have thus far.

```
//awk.awk file
    BEGIN {
        FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    }
    
    {
        print "NF = ", NF
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
            printf("$%d = <%s>\n", i, $i)
        }
    }
$ gawk -f awk.awk schools.csv
```

Desire output would just be

108 BLVD, SE or "108 BLVD, SE"

Comment: shouldn't ```$11``` be ```$i```?

Comment: @vgersh99 yes, sorry, I just edited my question

Comment: Use `"` as FS.  Then the address is in field 6.

Comment: @vgersh99 my file is 600,000 lines and it print every line but I just want the third column where the string is over 10 characters

Comment: @Shultz, so instead of the ```for``` loop, do ```if (length($3) >10)  print $3```. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @WilliamPursell what do you mean? aws FS = " 'length($3) > = 10 {print $3} '  ?

Comment: `awk 'length($6) > 10' FS='"' input-file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as you are already using GNU awk, you could utilize `gensub` to remove leading and trailing double quotes for `length`:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN {
    FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")" 
}
length(gensub(/^\"|\"$/,"","g",$3))>=10 {
    print $3
}' file
```

Output:

```
"103 avenue"
"108 BLVD, SE"
"MLK drive 1004"
```

If you want the output without the double quotes as well:

```
{
    gsub(/^"|"$/,"",$3)
    if(length($3)>=10)
        print $3
}
```